# AWS SDK: Get CallCount of CloudWatchLogs:PutLogEvents API Usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have an Alert in CloudWatch that get the metric CallCount for resource PutLogEvents type API and service Logs (CloudWatchLogs) on the namespace AWS/Usage.

It is useful to compare it with the limit of this resource (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/cloudwatch_limits_cwl.html)

*The maximum batch size of a PutLogEvents request is 1MB.*

*800 transactions per second per account per Region, except for the
following Regions where the quota is 1500 transactions per second
per account per Region: US East (N. Virginia), US West (Oregon),
and Europe (Ireland). You can request an increase to the per-second
throttling quota by using the Service Quotas service.*

There is any way to get this data using the SDK?

I'm trying with Aws\CloudWatch\CloudWatchClient and getMetricStatistics. Is that the correct way?

Any advice?

```php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\CloudWatch\CloudWatchClient; 
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

$cloudWatchClient = new CloudWatchClient([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => '*******************',
        'secret' => '*******************',
    ]
]);

$dimensions = [
    [
        'Name' => 'Service',
        'Value' => 'Logs'
    ],
    [
        'Name' => 'Resource',
        'Value'=> 'PutLogEvents'
    ],
    [
        'Name' => 'Type',
        'Value' => 'API'
    ]
];


$startTime = strtotime('-3 hours');
$endTime = strtotime('now');
$period = 300; // Seconds. (5 minutes = 300 seconds.)
$statistics = array('Average');
$unit = 'None';


$result = $cloudWatchClient->getMetricStatistics([
    'Namespace' => 'AWS/Usage',
    'MetricName' => 'CallCount',
    'Dimensions' => $dimensions,
    'StartTime' => $startTime,
    'EndTime' => $endTime,
    'Period' => $period,
    'Statistics' => $statistics,
    'Unit' => $unit
]);

echo $result;
```

I got ....

```
Model Data
----------
Data can be retrieved from the model object using the get() method of the
model (e.g., `$result->get($key)`) or "accessing the result like an
associative array (e.g. `$result['key']`). You can also execute JMESPath expressions on the result data using the search() method.

{
    "Label": "CallCount",
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2023-07-13T14:12:00+00:00",
            "Sum": 8014,
            "Unit": "None"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2023-07-13T14:16:00+00:00",
            "Sum": 7517,
            "Unit": "None"
        },
        {  
            "Timestamp": "2023-07-13T14:15:00+00:00",
            "Sum": 8045,
            "Unit": "None"
        },
        {
             "Timestamp": "2023-07-13T14:14:00+00:00",
             "Sum": 8044,
             "Unit": "None"
         },
         {
            "Timestamp": "2023-07-13T14:13:00+00:00",
            "Sum": 8012,
            "Unit": "None"
         }
    ],
    "@metadata": {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "effectiveUri": "https:\/\/monitoring.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
        "headers": {
            "x-amzn-requestid": "54ebf1ed-0d9d-4694-bbdc-50fcd509a2a3",
            "content-type": "text\/xml",
            "content-length": "332",
            "date": "Thu, 13 Jul 2023 13:58:19 GMT"
        },
        "transferStats": {
            "http": [
                []
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Since

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GetMetricStatistics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricStatistics.html) lets you fetch calculated statistics, such as max, min, average but there is also [GetMetricData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricData.html) which might be more what you need. [This example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/code-library/latest/ug/cloudwatch_example_cloudwatch_GetStartedMetricsDashboardsAlarms_section.html) is not yet available in PHP, but if you are familiar with C#, python or Java, it demonstrates several of the metric operations in a runnable example.